# BeautifulSoup not working cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup' from partially initialized module 'bs4'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, importerror

I keep getting error when trying to import Beautiful Soup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup' from partially initialized module 
'bs4' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: what is your file name? See if you have any other files called bs4 in the same directory or try reinstalling the module

Answer (score 12):

Try renaming python file that you working on from bs4 to something else. Maybe you named some other file in same directory bs4 so you must change it !

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the similar issue and was able to fix it by force reinstalling the package:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4
```